Remove quotes from beginning and end from list
I have an excel spreadsheet that has a column of AWS EBS volumes that I want to use as a list to delete using my boto3 python script. The script displays the volumes with initial and trailing quotes. I am getting a malformed string error, and learned I have to strip out the initial and trailing quotes out, but I am getting an error. The end goal is to use this list of volumes to be deleted using the boto3 delete_volume api call
import boto3 
import pprint
from openpyxl import load_workbook
AWS_REGION = "us-gov-west-1"
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name = AWS_REGION)

wb = load_workbook("WORKBOOK1.xlsx")  
ws = wb['Sheet1']  
column = ws['D']  
column_list = [column[x].value for x in range(len(column))]
stripped_column_list = column_list.strip(",")
pprint.pprint(stripped_column_list)

ec2_info = ec2.delete_volume(
    VolumeId = stripped_column_list
    DryRun = True
)


Which gives me this list.
['Volume Id vol-00a1f3aff3ff57b01 vol-04bd4cada863ee544 vol-02147928b7cb0e19e '
 'vol-0079ea32b16aeede1 vol-06097f05fbcab73db vol-0b80038092795093a '
 'vol-0217cbc5059c93843 vol-04bc423f2e9c53198 vol-05335afa0249b342a '
 'vol-0cb37e8948953fff5 vol-038518daeeb9c6602 vol-04a8671f9029ce376 '
 'vol-0ec9998450fee4df9 vol-01a7459966f7ac89f vol-05a66a16f8fd8b216 '
 'vol-0f9c0d20097d4db17 vol-0d96a5fadd7e628c3 vol-096f66a8746604d81 ']

I have been unable to figure out how to remove the initial and trailing quotes.
The goal is to use a for loop to iterate over the ec2_info variable to delete each of the volumes.

there are no quotes in the strings in your list.

The quotes aren't in the list. This is just how pprint() shows a list of strings, it adds the quotes to indicate that the elements are strings.

pprint.pprint(strpped_column_list[0]) to realize that the quotes are not part of a list, but rather signify that the list elements are strings. The quotes themselves are not part of the strings (nor the printed output, for that matter)

can @Barmar can you post as answer? this was succinct and explained well. thanks inspectorg4dget i will note that

This type of question has been asked and answered many times before, there's no point in my writing another. Unfortunately I don't have a link to a duplicate

The strip method is meant for strings,but you are trying to call strip(",") on a list and comma isnt their in original list.
Use list comprehension:
Stripped_column_list=[item.strip() for item in column_list]

itrate and delete volumes:
for volume_id in stripped_column_list:
  ec2_info=ec2.delete_volume(
      volumeId=volume_id,
      DryRun=True)
  pprint.pprint(ec2_info)

